# zf2 url viewhelper returning parent url even when invoked with child route

Tags: routes, zend-framework2, view-helpers

I have this route

```
 'restaurant' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/restaurant[/:name]',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'restaurant',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'book' => array(
                        'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/book',
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                                'action'     => 'book',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

when I invoke the url viewhelper like so `$this->url('restaurant/book', array('name' => $slug))` i expect the return url to be `/restaurant/some-slug-here/book`..but instead i get `/restaurant/some-slug-here`, without the book part....

It gets the child route, as if i change "book" to anything else in the child_routes, it throws an error...but it does not seem to form the correct url.

Also, the route `/restaurant/some-slug-here/book` works when typed in manually.

edit1: i tried to invoke it like so `$this->url('restaurant/book', array(), array(), true)` from the parent page..still nothing..

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you sure that helper call is causing that output?

Comment: well, the code looks like   ` <div class="post-content span12 first">
            <?php $slug = $this->slugify($restaurant->getName()) . '-' . $restaurant->getId(); ?>
            <a href="<?php $this->url('restaurant/book', array('name' => $slug))?>" class="btn btn-large btn-success">Book Now!</a>
        </div>`

Comment: And when right click -> inspect element, it shows the wrong url....

Comment: got it...I was doing <?php $this->url() ?>....instead of <?=$this->url()?> or <?php echo $this->url() ?> and an anchor without href, links to the same page ....I should take a break..i am too tired ... Thanks for your help Tim!